# Implementing safe areas with Infinite Container pull to refresh

Tags: codenameone

How can I set the safe area for pull to refresh? I have a form with with an infinite container. I set the IC with safe area ic.setSafeArea(true). When I rotate the screen the safe area is respected(see image 1). If i pull to refresh the safe area is not respected (see image 2). With the below code taken from the InfiniteContainerSample, how can I ensure the safe area is respected after pull to refresh?

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95rcz.png)
[image: image 2]

```
public void showForm() {
    Form hi = new Form("InfiniteContainer", new BorderLayout());

    Style s = UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("MultiLine1");
    FontImage p = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_PORTRAIT, s);
    EncodedImage placeholder = EncodedImage.createFromImage(p.scaled(p.getWidth() * 3, p.getHeight() * 3), false);

    InfiniteContainer ic = new InfiniteContainer() {
        @Override
        public Component[] fetchComponents(int index, int amount) {
            java.util.List<Map<String, Object>> data = fetchPropertyData("Leeds");
            MultiButton[] cmps = new MultiButton[data.size()];
            for(int iter = 0 ; iter < cmps.length ; iter++) {

                Map<String, Object> currentListing = data.get(iter);
                if(currentListing == null) {
                    return null;
                }
                String thumb_url = (String)currentListing.get("thumb_url");
                String guid = (String)currentListing.get("guid");
                String summary = (String)currentListing.get("summary");
                cmps[iter] = new MultiButton(summary);
                cmps[iter].setIcon(URLImage.createToStorage(placeholder, guid, thumb_url));
            }

            return cmps;
        }
    };
    ic.setUIID("Blue");
    ic.setSafeArea(true);
    ic.addComponent(new Label("This is a test"));
    hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, ic);
    hi.show();
}
int pageNumber = 1;
java.util.List<Map<String, Object>> fetchPropertyData(String text) {
    try {
        ConnectionRequest r = new ConnectionRequest();
        r.setPost(false);
        r.setUrl("http://api.nestoria.co.uk/api");
        r.addArgument("pretty", "0");
        r.addArgument("action", "search_listings");
        r.addArgument("encoding", "json");
        r.addArgument("listing_type", "buy");
        r.addArgument("page", "" + pageNumber);
        pageNumber++;
        r.addArgument("country", "uk");
        r.addArgument("place_name", text);
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(r);
        Map<String,Object> result = new JSONParser().parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(r.getResponseData()), "UTF-8"));
        Map<String, Object> response = (Map<String, Object>)result.get("response");
        return (java.util.List<Map<String, Object>>)response.get("listings");
    } catch(Exception err) {
        Log.e(err);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be an issue with pull to refresh, I need to check that,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this.  This has been fixed on [github](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/c7834b8cd920198e8005ddefbff58124289006c2).  It will be included in the next release on Friday.